# Doctrine: Unknown database type bit requested, but I don't use "bit"

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Trying to update schema, I get this error message:

```
bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql
```

> [Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException]
>     Unknown database type bit requested, Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\MySqlPlatform may not support it.

The problem is, I don't use any *bit* or *boolean* property in any of my entities. As the message doesn't say which field or entity is affected I can't correct it.

A grep in entity folder tree doesn't help:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -inH '(^| )bit($| )' {} \;
find . -type f -exec grep -inH '(^| )boolean($| )' {} \;
```

Both return empty set (executed from entity folder root).

Also, I added this in my *config.yml*, but doesn't have effect:

```
doctrine:
  dbal:
      mapping_types:
          enum: string
          bit: boolean
```

Any ideas where to look or what to change?
(I use symfony 3)

Comment: Not using any unusual 3rd party bundles?

Comment: Maybe: friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle, incenteev/composer-parameter-handler, symfony/polyfill-apcu, how can I detect the source of the problem?

Comment: Start by grepping the vendor folder for 'bit'. Of course I would have expected any bundle using a bit data type to properly register it.  And by the way, I'm pretty sure mapping types refer to the orm and not the dbal connection object.  But I could be wrong.  And bit data type is not the same as boolean so drop the boolean stuff.

Comment: don't find anything, maybe search command is nor formed properly

Comment: find . -exec grep -li bit {} \;  Should do the trick though normally I just use my IDE's search function. The jsrouting bundle is the only suspicious one.  I would imagine that it loads a bunch of other ones as well.

Comment: Crazy, today the problem dissapeared, what I did, just in case somebody gets something similar is: 1- remove `jsrouting-bundle` from `composer.json`, 2- execute `compser.phar update`, 3- excute `doctrine:sechema:update`, 4- restore `jsrouting-bundle` in `composer.json`, 5- execute `compser.phar update`, after this, `doctrine:sechema:update` is not throwing errors